# How can the difference between "Priority Date" and "Filing Date" be greater than 1 year?

Tags: filing, uspto, provisional, priority

For most patents (at least the ones I looked at) there is no more than 1 year difference between "Priority Date" and "Filing Date": often exactly 1 year, and if not, just under 1 year.

This must be due to the fact that one has 1 year to do the actual filing after the provisional one.

However, rarely, the delay between "Priority Date" and "Filing Date" is significantly more than 1 year.

How is this legally possible?

Comment: Can you link a specific example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is likely you are seeing the effects of a continuation (or divisional, outside of the US). The continuation retains the priority date of its parent, but has a much later filing date.

By way of example:

- A Canadian application (CA1) is filed on 1 Jun 2012. CA1 therefore has a filing date of 1 Jun 2012, but no priority date.
- A US application (US1) claiming priority to CA1 is filed on 31 May 2013 (within 12 months of CA1). US1 therefore has a filing date of 31 May 2013, and a priority date of 1 Jun 2012.
- A US continuation (US2) is filed from US1 on 1 Oct 2016. US2 retains the priority claims of its parent (US1). US2 therefore has a filing date of 1 Oct 2016, and a priority date of 1 Jun 2012.

Comment: It might be worth to add that in those cases the patent term is not 20 years from the filing date but from the first parents filing date. (/Us patents before they changed from 17 after grant).

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean a difference of years, not days or weeks, but some countries now allow you to miss the 1 year priority date. Details in this [Q/A](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/18445/is-12-month-paris-convention-priority-claim-deadline-extendable), which discusses a two months grace period some countries give.