# 18 mo application publication start from continuation filing date or original filing date?

Tags: pre-grant, uspublication

When a continuation application is filed, does publication of the patent application occur 18 mo. after the original application or the continuation filing date (assuming 18 mo. disclosure is required)?  So in the example listed in this post [How can the difference between "Priority Date" and "Filing Date" be greater than 1 year?](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/18020/how-can-the-difference-between-priority-date-and-filing-date-be-greater-than), does U.S. publication occur 18 mo. after 31 May 2013 or 1 Oct. 2016?

Also, my understanding is that Canada would publish the application in its jurisdiction 18 mo. after 1 Jun. 2012, right?